# Org-mode - What internals make python session mode so picky with blank lines?

Tags: org-mode, python, org-babel

I understand and work around the limitation of session mode python code blocks. But why is it like this?

Is it possible that this could be fixed so that people don't have to adjust their usage patterns?

Another thing is output e.g.:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session py1 :results output raw
  d = 0
  for a in range(3):
      pass

  print "oh yeah"

#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:

... ... >>> oh yeah
```

All the ellipses and prompts are quite annoying.
I understand that this is not a trivial matter but session mode is so powerful and I want to see it be as good as possible.

Can someone please explain the reason for these blemishes?

Comment: I think this is the most recent ML post on the topic: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/95980/focus=96076